# microsoft visual studio "the project does not contain rule configuration "

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to create a new C++ project in Microsoft Visual Studio, it shows the error "The project does not contain rule ConfigurationGeneral".

[image]

Comment: I don't get that problem. Perhaps you need to reinstall it.

Comment: I have installed 3 times
but still the problem

Comment: Oh... It could something old that is left somewhere in the registry or similar. Perhaps you can get online help from Microsoft to have them fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Currently its hard to know what specific problem you have, since we don't know you setup, probably the C++ module isn't installed, what you have exactly done i.e. what project and how did you create and what specific error you got.

Comment: Hi 
after click create project show error "the project does not contain rule configuration"

Comment: look image in top

Comment: [Don't post links to images] ( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3537677 ) To support your text, if the image still helps post it like describered here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? It doesn't look like that for me (VS2019).

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-create-any-project-fresh-install-vs2019-commu/1063153

Comment: has solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue just hours ago.
What worked for me: Unistalled Visual Studio and installed again.